# How to go about backpacking to Europe for the first time

Tags: budget, europe, sightseeing, planning, backpacking

I'm trying to plan my first backpack trip to Europe but not sure how to go about planning. My goal to backpacking Europe is to experience the culture and go sight seeing.

What are some tips/advice I could use to help plan out my trip? Since I've never been to Europe I don't know what to expect and how long I should stay in each city. I would like to spend the least amount of money but still experience the culture and scenery. Also how do most of you travel within the cities?

Comment: Tossed a close vote for the reasons cited below: not fit for Q&A.

Comment: Hi zLan - welcome to Travel.SE.  A great topic, however the question as it stands can't easily be objectively answered and will likely result in a discussion.  If you please could have a read of the [faq] and Ginamin's response below, and then you're welcome to ask *specific* questions which the community will be very eager to help you with! We love travel and love talking about it as well, and many have backpacked in Europe - but your question as it stands could start off several books worth of subjective answers! Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Asking this here you will get a dozen different answers and all of them will be correct. Everyone backpacks differently... some people love tents, some people love hostels. I know a guy who spent a month traveling Japan, but would only crash in abandoned houses.

I would recommend you read up on some basic backpacking guides. There are a dozen out there. I pursued [one for you quick and thought it was pretty informative](http://www.euro-backpacker.com/planning/). Only you can decide where you want to go, although people here will be glad to give you some advice about specific locations.

I would recommend you read a few guides... buy a travel guide (if you want to save money 'Europe on a Shoestring' is quite handy). Then, when you have some specific questions that can be answered in a Q&A format, ask them here and we will be happy to help you in any way we can.